# How Bluetooth Low Energy security works between Android app and BLE devices?

Tags: android, security, encryption, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm studying the Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE) protocol (v4.2), and in particular its security features.
I'm trying to understand how the encryption of data transmitted between a mobile App and a BLE device works.

The official documentation (v4.2) specifies the methods to encrypt data, authenticate the devices, generate the keys used in the encryption and pairing phase, etc..

First doubt (I want to be sure to have understood some concepts):
all these functions are implemented in the host level, so if I want to encrypt data transmitted between an App (Android) and a BLE device (like a fitness tracker), 
do I have to implement (or enable) these methods on the BLE device? 
In this way, the developer should only care about the implementation of these features on the BLE device, since the Android Bluetooth stack just support these features. Am I right?
If I'm wrong, what is the right way to implement these features (on both mobile app and BLE device)?

Second doubt:
Why some BLE devices, implement their own cryptography, on top the GATT protocol, instead using the security features provided by the SIG?

Third and last doubt:
Are the security features specified by the SIG mandatory or are optional?

As you can see I have some doubts, and maybe some questions could be silly, so if someone could clarify how the security mechanisms (like encryption) can be implemented between an App and a BLE device, 
and at which levels these features are implemented (OS or application level), I will appreciate a lot.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you use the standard BLE encryption, it is actually the link layer at the controller that does the encryption/decryption/verifying auth tags. But it's the host layer (SMP) that defines how two devices pair, bond and exchange keys. It's also that layer that tells the link layer to start encryption using the exchanged keys. On Android and iOS, it's the OS that manages the pairing and bonding and implements the SMP. Whether or not Bluetooth pairing/bonding/encryption is used is fully up to the device, and is optional. If it's not supported it must still support to send the error code "Pairing Not Supported"

The Bluetooth standard only has one "use case". This use case is to provide a method for securing the link between two devices so that, after bonding, no one should be able to impersonate a device or be able to manipulate or decrypt the traffic. As you might know, the "LE Legacy Pairing" which is the only pairing method specified up to Bluetooth v4.1, has several flaws that makes it unsecure if the attacker sniffs the traffic during pairing (both for "Just works" and "MITM/passkey entry", but not OOB). The new "LE Secure Connections" defined by Bluetooth v4.2 however uses Diffie Hellman to make it more secure.

Even though Bluetooth pairing itself provides security, there are some flaws in both the Android API and the iOS API that still may not be enough for an app developer if good security is needed. Notably, iOS does not provide any API whatsoever to detect if a given device is actually bonded or if a link is encrypted. It does however show a popup to the user when the pairing starts, but the app knows nothing about that pairing. So, from an iOS app's point of view, you **don't** know:

1. If you have paired to the device.
2. If you talk to a genuine device or a chinese copy.
3. The security level, i.e. if the pairing used Just Works, MITM legacy pairing or LE Secure Connections.
4. If the current link is encrypted.

Android is a little bit better. There the app can at least know if the device is bonded or not (but not the other three). There is also an API "createBond" to start the bonding process. The Windows API is much better here, since you can enforce encrypted link when doing GATT operations.

Any of these reasons may be enough for a developer to implement the security from scratch on top of GATT instead. In particular one often common use case is that the developer wants the use case "log in to the peripheral" with a PIN or password. The Bluetooth standard does not support that use case in any way (and no, using "MITM protected pairing with *static* passkey" doesn't work, since that protocol by design reveals the passkey after one or a few tries).

Anyway, if you develop your own peripheral with your own hardware and want to use the Bluetooth standard's pairing/bonding/encryption, the SDKs by the manufacturers of the BLE chips have usually already implemented this. However, you still need to set it up correctly for it to work. Usually you only have to configure some parameters (like if you have a display or the user can enter a passkey) and then the rest is automatically handled internally by their SDK.

**UPDATE:**

Source code for Android can be found at https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/bt/, https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Bluetooth/ and https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/bluetooth.

Comment: That's exacly what I was looking for. I have other 2 questions: where can I find the source code of the Android bluetooth stack? I would like to take a deeper look into the Android flaws. Could you recommend some reading, resources etc..?

Comment: I added locations for the Android bluetooth source code to the answer. Regarding your second question, I haven't that much more to say but if you wonder about something particular, ask me. Basically, number 3 and 4 is pretty bad that they don't have an API to tell the current security of a link, or an option to enforce a security level when you do a GATT operation.

Comment: I'm reading again the official documentation. About the Passkey Entry method, used in LE Legacy Pairing, the TK used for generating the STK, is provided by a user input passkey + padding (the initiator display and the responder inputs or viceversa). So,according to your answers, there isn't an API in Android that support these feature, am I right? I've used different apps that ask me to insert a pin that is displayed on the device, but I think that this pin is not used for creating the TK, but instead in some kind of autentication or custom cryptography build over GATT. Am I right?

Comment: Yes but that dialog is shown automatically by the system and not by the app. And in legacy pairing that passkey equals the TK.

Comment: Many thanks for you time. So it means that if passkey is used, the (Android) OS handles the request, shows the dialog, and uses the pin provided by the user to create the TK. All these features are handled in the OS and not in the App level am I right?

Comment: Correct. But there still seems to exist an api "setPin" which seems to be possible to use to programmatically enter the pin (instead of the user enters it). But even if this works, this doesn't really solve any of the problems.